# How to disable the range option in http request header?

Tags: http

While downloading a PDF via google chrome, i receive a 206 status response from the server. After going through the RFC, i found out that the client is making a conditional GET request appending a range header. is there any way to disable the range header while making the request or using a different browser is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server are you using?

This is the apache documentation for mod_headers. You can set the Accept-Ranges header to none

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

Try setting "Accept-Ranges none" in the httpd.conf file.

The mod_headers module must be loaded in the server too.

Also, when the request of a pdf or often streamed file it's done through chrome or an adobe plugin or so (other plugins), they will always attempt to do the GET request with Range:0- and try partial requests of the file to show content to the user (first pages of the pdf if the pdf is big) and manage the download so the server will respond with 206 status.

Comment: I am not sure of the server that I am accessing. But I thought it was more of a client side issue. Anyways thanks for the response on the apache. And issue that i mentioned worked for one client machine and failed for the other.

Comment: So do we need to add the statement "Accept-Ranges: none" in the httpd.conf file of the Server?

Comment: Is the pdf file large? When files are large or connection is bad, servers throw a 206 status. Normally browsers get the 206 and manage the download in parts for you. Have you tried with another browser just in case?

Comment: If the "Accept-Ranges" feature on the server is active, files can be downloaded in parts (normally active if the server offers big files)

Comment: Yes, set "Accept-Ranges: none" in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Forgot to say that the mod_headers module must be loaded in the server.

Comment: Got it. Un-comment this: LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

Comment: so will this process solve the problem of viewing incomplete PDF's?? just want to confirm before i proceed since it is quite important not to falter...

Comment: Did you test if you still have the problem? If the server is set to "Accept-Ranges: none" you can confirm it won't try to send the file in "packages", so if the connection is bad it will take a long time to download the file or it will give you a 4xx failure response (client side problem: permissions (not the case), client (browser) does not meet requirements for the download, etc.). Anyway, in this case you are sure that if there is a problem, it won't be related to the ranges anymore.

Comment: yet to try it out. Will let you know the result of it.

Comment: I did add the statement: Accept-Ranges: none and while restarting the server i get this error: The requested operation failed. Let me know how to proceed

Comment: It is "Header set Accept-Ranges none". Also, even after restarting the server, i still get the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" in my response header. Please help.

Comment: First of all lets try a "Header set Accept-Ranges none
" in your .htaccess file too. Apart, are you using a shared server? Dedicated?

Comment: where do i find the .htaccess file? I am using a dedicated server.

Comment: It is normally in the root directory of each website, and you can create one for each folder. The options in that file apply anytime someone requests a webpage located in that folder or subfolders.

Comment: Anyway i think you have correctly set the Accept-Ranges none on the server, but just to check. Also, even if the server has Accept-ranges set to none you can still receive a header saying Accept-ranges:bytes that kind of tells you the server is capable of this option even if its not enabled on it. You can read about this here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.server.caudium.general/715, but i'm afraid its not related toy our problem (just info).

Comment: Using Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) server.

Comment: Making a GET request with the header Range: bytes=10- Hence i expect 200 ok and not 206.

Comment: Before continuing... are you just downloading the file or are you using Acrobat reader to request the file and show it? Did you try with firefox, IE?

Comment: right now, i have setup my own Apache server to replicate the issue. I am not downloading from any site. I am just pinging my own computer and making GET requests to this server.

Comment: And the requests fail the download?

Comment: It completes the request. But i get a 206 response instead of a 200 OK. My aim to is set the range header in the request and enable the server not to honor it and send out a 200 OK response.

Comment: I've just read Chrome does always a Range: 0- request by default for pdfs, videos and other possible big file content. Don't exactly know if it does the request through the adobe plugin and that's maybe the reason you get a 206 response even if you finally get the whole file (because you always do a partial request by default). This partial request is done to show the first pages of the pdf asap before the total download finishes.

Comment: You can read part of this here: http://serverfault.com/questions/61424/why-are-we-seeing-apache-206-partial-responses-for-pdf-downloads

Comment: How are you making the GET requests now?

Comment: I am using an extension for Chrome - Advanced REST client to make the GET requests

Comment: Then if you have the adobe plugin installed there you have the why of the 206 response.

Comment: When the plugin knows the file was downloaded completely it stops the partial requests. I'm almost sure that if you code a GET request with an external program or library the server will respond with a 200 when downloaded.

Comment: I'm curious. Was your problem solved or what did you find about it?

Comment: I started using a different PDF viewer which solved the issue. But i am not sure of this workaround. Anyways thanks for the help! Appreciated!

Comment: I guess that was the problem, you weren't managing the requests, but the plugin or the pdf viewer, so you couldn't really set the values of the request. I'll modify the answer to see if it fits you.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) enabled, then add this to your Apache config:

```
<Files *.pdf>
    Header set Accept-Ranges none 
</Files>
```

The issue you're experiencing is a [documented bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436964): when a user tries to save a PDF file before the whole file has had a chance to download, the resulting file is corrupted. This fix stops Chrome from making partial requests for the file.