# Chrome download link with basic auth doesn't work, in FF and Postman it does

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, download, href

We provide users the possibility to download some files. Access to the files is protected by basic auth.
After entering their credentials, the user receives an overview of the files, he can download.

Example:

1. he surfs at https://test.com/documents/
2. he enters credentials:
3. HTML-page (index) with a list of all downloadable files in this folder incl. link (https://test.com/documents/file1.pdf...) are shown.

Each link to a file is structured as following:

```
<a href="document.pdf" download>Document</a>
```

- After entering the credentials I can access the index file in FF and
  Chrome. => Basic auth. works
- I can download the file in Firefox
- Chrome gives me a 403 forbidden error

=> This doesn't make any sense, as I can see the index-page in Chrome, which is protected by the same htaccess.

When I try to reconstruct this with postman, I can download the file as well:

Here is the Chrome request headers:

```
GET /documents/file1.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic base64_passwd
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: _et_coid=ddfsdfsdf; SameSite=None
Range: bytes=0-786431
If-Range: "224c1c-5a3b39e8694da"
```

Firefox headers:

```
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xm…ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization: Basic base64_passwd
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
DNT 1
Host test.com
Pragma no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
```

htaccess-file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/pathToHTPASSWD/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

I was able to narrow down the area of problem. The apache logs mentions that mod_security throws an error:

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). String match "bytes=0-" at REQUEST_HEADERS:Range. [file ".../httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf"] [line "428"] [id "958291"] [rev "2"] [msg "Range: field exists and begins with 0."] [data "bytes=0-786431"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "6"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_HREQ"] [hostname "test.com"] [uri "/pathToFile/test.pdf"] [unique_id "Xp4Yavc8gbf6TnFOQIGlNwADABE"]
```

It seems that the mod_security rule stops at reading 0 instead of reading the whole: bytes=0-786431

Some recommend another rule => https://serverfault.com/questions/610940/apache-mod-security-crs-blocking-pdf-files

others recommend setting the header "Accept-Ranges none"
[How to disable the range option in http request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894640/how-to-disable-the-range-option-in-http-request-header#)

Personally I would think the rule (part of ModSecurity Core Rules) has a bug.

What is the best way to solve this?

If you need more information, let me know.

Any hints are welcome!

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I just had the same problem. Might be that Chrome does not understand the download attribute in links in addition to Basic Auth. Removing the download attribute might help (but chrome might try to display the contents instead of downloading depending on filetype).